# Getting two distinct answers to a limits problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across a problem of limits which is as follows:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1+ \tan x}\right)^{1/x^2}e^{1/x}$$
I tried to solve the problem by using two approaches :

Approach 1 :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{1}{1+ \tan x})^{1/x^2}e^{x/x^2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}[\frac{e^x}{1+ \tan x}]^{1/x^2}$$
Then as it has now become a limit of the form 1 raised to the power infinity , I used the formula  which is

> Given $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$$ then
> $$\lim_{x\to a} f^{g} = e^{\lim_{x\to a}{(f-1)g}}\quad  $$

Which gives me

$$e^{(e^x-1-\tan x)/x^2(1+\tan x)}$$
And then by using L'Hôpital rule twice in the power of $e$, I get the answer $$e^{1/2}.$$

**Approach 2:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}[\frac{1}{1+ \tan x}]^{1/x^2}e^{1/x}$$
I use the formula of 1 raised to power infinity in the denominator which gives me
$$ e^{1/x}/e^{\tan x/x^2}$$

Substituting $\tan x$ by $x$, I get the answer as $1$.
But I really don’t understand because the two approaches give me distinct answers. I think using the formula of 1 raised to the power infinity in the denominator in the second approach might be incorrect to use but I am not sure at all though. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: By $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+ tan x}^{1/x^2}e^{1/x}$ do you mean $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1+ \tan x}\right)^{1/x^2}e^{1/x}$?

Comment: @Joe Yes I mean this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are correctly applying the formula, which means
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+\tan(x)},\qquad g(x)=1/x^2
$$
and so $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-1)g(x)=1/2$, yielding the correct answer
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}\right)^{1/x^2}e^{1/x}=\sqrt e.
$$

If I understand correctly your question, in the second case you would like to apply the formula with
$$
f(x)=\frac 1{1+\tan(x)},\qquad g(x)=1/x^2,
$$
but in such case  $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-1)g(x)$ is indeterminate and you cannot apply the formula. (More precisely  $\lim_{x\to 0_\pm}(f(x)-1)g(x)=\mp\infty$.)

Comment: In the second approach, I wish to consider f(x) as 1+tan x and g(x) as 1/x^2 and then use the formula which gives me $$e^{1/x }$$ in the denominator( which is indeterminate ) but it cancels out the $$e^{1/x}$$ in the numerator which gives me the answer  1. So is there a problem in using the 1 to the power infinity formula if it gives an indeterminate form even if it cancels out with some other term?  Thanks !

Comment: You need to consider the full expansion $(1+tan(x))^{1/x^2}=exp(log(1+tan(x))/x^2)=exp(1/x-1/2+O(x))=\frac{exp(1/x)}{\sqrt e} (1+O(x))$, as $x\to 0$. Then you have the constant term $1/\sqrt e$ which you are neglecting if you just cancel out the divergent part $exp(1/x)$. The formula $(f(x)-1)g(x)$ loses some important information in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have understood the solution via this method but still I don’t understood why does directly using the formula gives the wrong answer because it obviously neglects the term containing $x^2$obtained via this solution. So if you could elaborate on how I can recognise if the formula could give an incorrect answer like is there any condition that this question isn’t fulfilling for the formula to be applicable. This is the first case I have seen in which the formula loses some important information so I am quite confused . Sorry for bothering !

Comment: In the general formulation which you mention in your post, if $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-1)g(x)$ is not finite you cannot expect the method to yield the correct answer; I suggest always to expand the logarithm of $f(x)$ near $x=a$ in such circumstances.

Moreover in the original formulation that you mention, no hypothesis are considered but they should be; I think that the correct hypothesis is that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-1)g(x)$ exists and is finite.